# Don't Answer Please: Windows 7 64 bit Cygwin Network Drive Mounting

Tags: windows-7, networking, mount, cygwin

I'm best described as a ferverish fumbler rather than some sort of expert. However, I have been around the block a few times.

I've just realised that in my new place of employment, my Windows 7 64 Bit laptop isn't seeing the network drives under cygwin the way it used to "by magic".

I can mount them using, amazingly, the mount command - or make this "permanent" in the /etc/fstab file. I can test that it works:

```
% mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
H: on /cygdrive/h type unknown (binary)
Z: on /cygdrive/z type unknown (binary)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

...which is lovely, except that it doesn't work:

```
% cd /cygdrive
% ls
c

%
```

Is there something else I need to do after mounting it? Why doesn't it automatically mount the network drives?

-- edit --

I was unaware that it is possible for other users to edit my posts. I was also unaware that is a violation of protocol to say "thanks in advance" or express similar sentiments. I'll find the answer another way. I find this unacceptable and won't be back. So long "Dave M", your mother must be very proud.